# Unable to click on 'Text' inside 'dropdown list'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1. Unable to click on 'Text' inside 'dropdown list'
2. When outputing the information to console it lists all the titles (Mr., Mrs...)
3. Im just unable to click on the .Mr text, any ideas? (I dont want to use send keys)

   ```
   public void selectOptionFromDropdownMenu(WebElement dropdown, String textToSearchFor) {
   List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
   dropdown.click();
   System.out.println(options.size());

   for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println("DEVIL!!!"  + options.get(i).getText());

       if(options.get(i).getText() == "Mr.") {
           options.get(i).click();
       }
   }
   ```

   }

[image]

```
<select id="titlefield" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="Salutation" ng-model="PersonalDetails.Salutation" ng-options="salut.id as salut.id for salut in Salutations" ng-required="FlowData.IsGuest" required="required">
<option class="ng-binding" value="">Please select</option>
<option value="0" label="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="1" label="Miss">Miss</option>
<option value="2" label="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="3" label="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="4" label="Dr.">Dr.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why are you not using as `new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("titlefield"))).selectByVisibleText("Mr.")`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void selectOptionFromDropdownMenu(WebElement dropdown, String textToSearchFor) {
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
Select selectDropdown = new Select(dropdown);
//dropdown.click();
System.out.println(options.size());

for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("DEVIL!!!"  + options.get(i).getText());

    if(options.get(i).getText().equals(textToSearchFor)) {
    selectDropdown.selectByVisibleText(textToSearchFor);
        //options.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user Select class here.

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("<use the id>")));
List<WebElement> elem = oSelect.getOptions();
int iSize = elem.size();
for(int i=0; i <iSize;i++)
    {
        String sValue = oSelect.getOptions().get(i).getText();
        oSelect.getOptions().get(i).click();
        System.out.println(sValue);
                if(sValue.equals("Miss"))
        {
            System.out.println("Position of the value is" +i);
            oSelect.selectByIndex(i);


            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element=//select[contains(@id,"titlefield")]/option[contains(@value,"0") and @label="Mr."]


public void javascriptclick(String element)
    { 
        WebElement webElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",webElement);   
        System.out.println("javascriptclick"+" "+ element);

    }
```