# Cannot count/print all options listed under listbox using selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this snippet. I'm trying to count/print all options listed under `country` listbox.

```
  <select id="country" class="text-box drop-down-list ng-pristine ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-class="{'text-box-error': form.country.$touched && form.country.$invalid}" ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries" ng-model="mv.country" name="country" required="" style="">
    <option translate="CUSTOMER_SUPPORT_COUNTRY_SELECT" value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option label="Afghanistan" value="string:Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option label="Aland Islands" value="string:Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option label="Albania" value="string:Albania">Albania</option>
    <option label="Algeria" value="string:Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option label="American Samoa" value="string:American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option label="Andorra" value="string:Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option label="Angola" value="string:Angola">Angola</option>
    <option label="Anguilla" value="string:Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option label="Antarctica" value="string:Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option label="Antigua and Barbuda" value="string:Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option label="Argentina" value="string:Argentina">Argentina</option>
```

I am getting count as a '1' though list box has many.

```
    WebElement X = driver.findElement(By.id("country"));
               Select s=new Select(X);
               List<WebElement> elementCount = s.getOptions();
               int itemSize = elementCount.size();`enter code here`
               System.out.println(itemSize);
                for(int i = 0; i < itemSize ; i++){
                    String optionsValue = elementCount.get(i).getText();
                    System.out.println(optionsValue);
```

Comment: did you forget to close your <select> tag?

Comment: Check if you have another element with `id="country"`

Comment: @Darshan - No,i just copied some part of HTML since list-box has around 40 options listed.

Comment: @Guy - No only one matching node id="country"

Comment: As u have used ng-options in select tag, options need to be load from java script. So try by giving some wait time before Select s=new Select(X) or WebElement X.

Comment: @vidya can you provide the URL for the page?

Comment: @Guy :- Thanks for suggestion, it solved my problem.

Comment: See My answer for these question, I have tried this code on my end, and it's working for me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224669/unable-to-click-on-text-inside-dropdown-list

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @guy,your suggestion had solved my issue.
I have added wait statement -thread.sleep() after select statement & it works.

```
 WebElement X = driver.findElement(By.id("country"));
       Select s=new Select(X);
       List<WebElement> elementCount = s.getOptions();
       Thread.sleep(2000);
      int itemSize = elementCount.size();
      /*    System.out.println(itemSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < itemSize ; i++){
            String optionsValue = elementCount.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(optionsValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

When we are using ng-options in select tag, options need to be load from java script. So, Elements will get loaded but options will take some time to load from java script. It can be avoided by using some wait time.